# How to pass URL with parameters in GET request in Flask?

Tags: python, url, flask

In Flask, I want to send an URL in the URL as a parameter with all its parameters

Here is a working example
`http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=717097101644637&set=a.456449604376056.98921.367116489976035&type=1&theater`

I couldn't find a way, because the moment I cal something like this, the url doesn't go true.

```
@app.route('/<url>', methods=['GET'])

def show(url):
    """ do something with it """
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thank you

Comment: try to use this : `@app.route('/<path:url>', methods=['GET'])`

Comment: That works to the point that it will remove all the parameters from the URL.

Comment: are you trying to print the url on the page ? or you're trying to deal with its data "json" ?

Comment: Trying to use the url, I don't care about the json. I want to achieve the same functionality, not get the same data.

Comment: The best I could come up to this moment is `url = request.url.replace(request.url_root,'')` for the URL and `@app.route('/<path:url>', methods=['GET'])` for the app.route.

Comment: That works ! but I will look for another way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I can't control if the URL is URL-encoded so the best thing I came along is this.

```
_url = request.url.replace(request.url_root,'')
url = urllib.unquote(_url)
```

Maybe it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at what Facebook returns for that URL:

```
{
   "id": "https://www.facebook.com/photo.php",
   "shares": 377224,
   "comments": 2
}
```

you will note that the query string params are being consumed by `graph.facebook.com` - they are *not* treated as part of the URL that is being submitted as a search param.  If you want to be able to get the whole URL *including* query string arguments, you will need to URL-encode the query string `your.url/https://www.facebook.com/photo.php%3Ffbid=717097101644637%26set=a.456449604376056.98921.367116489976035%26type=1%26theater`

Comment: I gave Facebook as the closest example. I know they don't do exactly what I wanted. Unfortunately I can't URL encode the whole string, because if you will paste the link into your browsers (at least in Safari) it will do exactly what happened there.